# asp.net mvc nuget loads 2 versions of jQuery Mobile CSS files

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, nuget

I'm using nuget to load jQuery and jQuery Mobile packages into my project.  Nuget is loading jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css and jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.min.css.  Which should I use?  Both?  What are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference is that the `jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.min.css` provides basic css styling while the `jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css` is the structure plus default theme swatches.

If you are using your own custom theme (maybe from [themeroller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/)) then you should be fine with just the structure file.  [Check out this page](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) for more information on different download configurations.